# How to save this type of time format 147:12:55 in postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql

I want to save the column Total working hours spent in a table and the format is 147:25:55  in postgresql from Excel sheet using PHP

Comment: interval it is...

Answer (score 1):

It is interval type. look here:

```
t=# select '147:25:55'::interval,justify_interval('147:25:55'::interval);
 interval  | justify_interval
-----------+------------------
 147:25:55 | 6 days 03:25:55
(1 row)
```